# how to bring a list from database ex(team1,team2,..) to a combobox using A METHOD

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

PS: I'm using also FXML and I have the `query()` method ready, just don't know how to join them together. If someone could help, it would be really nice :)

This is the `query()` method.

```java
@Override
public ArrayList<String> query(String q, String... search) {

    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        rs = statement.executeQuery(q);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (String s : search) {
                result.add(rs.getString(s));
                // System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [items](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#itemsProperty) property of `ComboBox` is an `ObservableList`. Use class [FXCollections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) to create an `ObservableList` and populate the list with the [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) data.

```
ObservableList<String> result = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
while (rs.next()) {
    for (String s : search) {
        result.addAll(rs.getString(s));
    }
}
ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
combo.setItems(result);
```